# Storing the result of Pig "GROUP BY" into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am looking for a way to store the output of "group by" command in pig into a file.

```
(D1,{(A1,null,C1,D1,E1),(null,B1,C1,D1,E1),(A2,null,null,D1,E2)})
(C1,{(A1,null,C1,D1,E1),(null,B1,C1,D1,E1)})
```

I have tried the store command, but the data is not being copied exactly how it is displayed.

```
store F into '/tmp/group_out';
```

Is there any alternative approach to copy the data into a file, in the same way as it is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default PigStorage function (invoked on using STORE) is configurable to some extent: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#pigstorage - you can set for example field and record delimiters.

You will have to implement a [custom Store UDF](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual#Store_Functions-1) if you need a special format for storing your data.